# Log out from my app (developed using facebook android sdk 4.0) and installed facebook native app

Tags: android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have added Facebook Log-in and Log-out functionality in my android app using Facebook SDK4.0.

I am having one particular problem for log-out from the native Facebook app.

My app is for an event where hundred users need to log-in and install event app to share their event experience. So, i need the log-in and log-out functionality to be as smooth as possible.

I am using Facebook new android SDK 4.0 log-in, log-out functionality. 
I have added this code in activity function and destroy function:

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
 LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

I have investigated during the log-in process when the log-in is successful and the app installation is done, Facebook SDK caches the current users login session for the native Facebook app. When the user logs out from my app, the user is still logged-in into his native facebook app.

This makes my event app journey very painful and time consuming. Because after every user's log-in and installation process from my app, i have to revisit the native Facebook app and then need to log out them manually from the native Facebook app.

This scenario is not the perfect solution for a busy event app!

Is there any one who also experienced similar or any idea, how the log out functionality can log out  users from both native Facebook app and my app?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you use AccountManager class from Android to remove the Facebook account?

```
public static void removeAccount(Context context){
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account[] localAccounts = am.getAccounts();

    for (int i=0; i<localAccounts.length; i++){
        if (localAccounts[i].type.equals("com.facebook.auth.login")){
            am.removeAccount(localAccounts[i], null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did not want to include account manager in my app. Needed functionality from Facebook SDK to do the logout things.

Comment: Facebook SDK 3 has `Session` class that provides method called `closeAndClearTokenInformation()` which you can call. However, the Session class has been deprecated in SDK 4. So, if you are willing to downgrade, here's the code for SDK 3: 

`Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }`

Comment: thanks for your input. I already know this and have also implemented in previous version. But i am looking the solution from SDK 4.0. look at my question title

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to log the user out of the main facebook app from your app.

Comment: yes. i know that. it is really very important to logout user from the app programmatically. shame facebook does not have this

Comment: Facebook... it's like a virus on your device Once connected, you can never get rid of it